# .substring and whitespace, Java

Tags: java, string, substring

I was playing around with the .substring method in Java and ran into an error I don't understand. If I have a string representing a forecast:

```
String forecast = "Sat, 7 Feb - Snow - -8/-13"
```

I can isolate the temperature data by calling

```
int lastWhitespaceIndex = forecast.lastIndexOf(" ");
int highs = Integer.parseInt(forecast.substring(lastWhitespaceIndex + 1));
```

However, if I change the second line to

```
int highs = Integer.parseInt(forecast.substring(lastWhitespaceIndex));
```

My program crashes. Is there some rule about not allowing a string to start with whitespace that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))  clearly states:

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.

So, no whitespace to start.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the substring will return `-8/-13` and that slash is no diget so this will fail. Split it at the slash and you are done.

```
int lastWhitespaceIndex = forecast.lastIndexOf(" ");
int lastSlashIndex = forecast.lastIndexOf("/");
int highs = Integer.parseInt(forecast.substring(lastWhitespaceIndex + 1, lastSlashIndex));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my test both approches faild. If you use [Integer.parse(value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) the value can only contains a number. If not You get a `NumberFormatException`.

> public static int parseInt(String s)
>                       throws NumberFormatException 
>   Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.
>
> Parameters:s - a String containing the int representation to be parsed
>
> Returns:the integer value represented by the argument in decimal. 
>   Throws: NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a
>   parsable integer.